# INSERT sql statement based on condition from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-insert, where-clause

I am trying to insert values into a table based on conditions from another table.  Ideally I would want something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_a SET user_id = 'contactId'
WHERE
    table_b.user_id = 'userA' 
    AND table_b.contact_id = 'contactId' 
    AND user_blocked = false
```

So before creating the new table_a entry, I want to make sure the user is not blocked by checking table_b.

I know I can't user INSERT with WHERE so not sure how I can do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you are looking for an [`INSERT ... SELECT` query](http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) :

```
INSERT INTO table_a (user_id) 
SELECT 'contactId'
FROM table_b AS tb
WHERE
    tb.user_id = 'userA' 
    AND tb.contact_id = 'contactId' 
    AND tb.user_blocked = false
```

If the subquery does not return anything, the outer `INSERT` will not happen.

Comment: does the value that you insert to table_a always need to be extracted from table_b?  Or can the above statement be written by inserting values in the outer INSERT

Comment: @alionthego : no it does not have to, you can write values as you want, like in the example I gave you, where I put value `'contact_id'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Insert From Select" . For example [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp) link will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use T-SQL for this, or build a stored procedure.

First check if the `user_id` is blocked in `table_b` and if the answer is false insert the value to `table_a`

This is an example:

```
DECLARE @user_id INT = 1234

IF ((SELECT user_blocked FROM table_b b WHERE b.USER_id = @user_id) = 'false')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table_a 
    VALUES(@user_id,....)
END
```